# I want to initialized every jtabbedpane's JTextarea with a new dynamic name?

Tags: java, swing

like

```
JTextArea ta[1]= new JTextArea();
```

bcoz I have many tabs in text editor and I want perform cut copy paste option. and if I use a same name for all tabs then all option work only last tab because that textarea initialized in end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Please take the time to read the advice provided here on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. As an aside, that word is spelled 'because' rather than 'bcoz' - it doesn't make you look cool to use 'hacker speak' (or whatever you want to think of it as) it just makes you look a fool.

Comment: Give each tab it's _own_ text component, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11007109/230513) for `JTextField`

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array of JTextArea objects, you can declare it like this:

```
JTextArea[] textAreas = new JTextArea[count];
```

where **count** is the number of objects you need

Then you can access it as normal:

```
textAreas[i]
```

where **i** is the index you need to access.

Comment: Not working sir...